# Configure bibitem command in tex4ebook/make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, bibitem

I am looking for a place to find how to configure the `\bibitem` tag in  tex4ebook/make4ht. All bibitems are inlined without </br>

I tried: `{\Configure{bibitem}{\NoFonts \HCode{</br>}}{}\EndNoFonts}}`

but the result is:

<a  id="Q1-5-19"></a>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNypG.jpg)</br>X1García,  P.  A.,  <span class="p1xi-">Compen....

I would like something like

</br> <a  id="Q1-5-19"></a>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNypG.jpg)X1García,  P.  A.,  <span class="p1xi-">Compen....

or inside some p or div or...

=================== act 2 =======================

i narrow the problem :
2 version :
    1 with <p>

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pxfonts} 
\begin{document}
oh \cite{1} aahhh
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1}Sample Bib text
\bibitem{2}Sample Bib text
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: with the p tag]

1 without <p>

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pxfonts} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
[block]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries \scshape \flushleft}
{\thechapter.}{0pt}{\hspace{5pt}\huge \bfseries \scshape}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\begin{document}
 oh \cite{1} aahhh
 \begin{thebibliography}{99}
 \bibitem{1}Sample Bib text
 \bibitem{2}Sample Bib text
 \end{thebibliography}
 \end{document}
```

[image: same without p tag]

the problem is that i need  the chapter thing in my document to format how chapter appears in the pdf and in the epub

Comment: We need a sample document

Comment: i don't understand.. it seems working...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by your titlesec configuration for `\chapter`. In particular, the line:

```
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries \scshape \flushleft}
```

The `\flushleft` command starts a list environment that overwrites `tex4ht` configuration for the bibliography, which is also a list environment. For use as a text switch, `\raggedright` is the correct command to use. So your TeX file should look like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pxfonts} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[block]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries \scshape\flushleft}
{\thechapter.}{0pt}{\hspace{5pt}\huge \bfseries \scshape}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello}

world

 oh \cite{1} 

 \begin{thebibliography}{99}
   % \expandafter\show\csname a:bibitem\endcsname
 \bibitem{1}Sample Bib text
 \bibitem{2}Sample Bib text
 \end{thebibliography}

 \end{document}
```

This is the result:

```xml
 <h2 class="likechapterHead"><a 
 id="x1-20001"></a>Bibliographie</h2>
    <div class="thebibliography">
    <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
  [1]<span class="bibsp">   </span></span><a 
 id="X1"></a>Sample Bib text
    </p>
    <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
  [2]<span class="bibsp">   </span></span><a 
 id="X2"></a>Sample Bib text</p></div>
```

[image]